# How to set multiple forms for different file types in JSPUI 5.6?

Tags: dspace

I want to define a form for each file type on different forms. Is this possible?

For example:

Article - Form type - 1

Journal - Form type - 2

Game - Form type - 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to set this up in `[dspace-src]/dspace/config/input-forms.xml` -- see [this page](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Submission+User+Interface#SubmissionUserInterface-CustomMetadata-entryPagesforSubmission) in the official DSpace documentation.

If you have separate collections for your different item types, just create three types of submission forms and assign them to the corresponding collections.

If you have collections that contain a mix of Article, Journal and Game items, you might want to set up a multi-page form and ask for the type on the first page. On the second page, you can then use the "Item type Based Metadata Collection" functionality to ask for some fields only for certain types.